# How to make GoJS link not to take shortest path between blocks

Tags: gojs

Layout :

```
 diagrams.toolManager.linkingTool.temporaryLink.routing = go.Link.Orthogonal;
 diagrams.toolManager.relinkingTool.temporaryLink.routing = go.Link.Orthogonal;
```

Link code:

```
this.go.Link,  // the whole link panel
            {
                routing: this.go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
                curve: this.go.Link.JumpOver,
                corner: 5, toShortLength: 4,
                relinkableFrom: true,
                relinkableTo: true,
                reshapable: true,
                resegmentable: true,
                toPortChanged:  (a, b, c) =>{ console.log(a,"test");},
                mouseEnter: (e, link) => { link.findObject("HIGHLIGHT").stroke = "rgba(30,144,255,0.2)"; },
                mouseLeave: (e, link) => { link.findObject("HIGHLIGHT").stroke = "transparent"; }
            },
```

Link line always reconnected to shortest path between blocks (from block left side  to block  right side )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine your nodes are acting as ports. You'll want to define multiple ports if you'd like to be able to connect to different sides of the node.

[Intro to Ports](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/ports.html)

Or maybe you want to set fromSpot and toSpots.

[Intro to Connection Points](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/connectionPoints.html)